# Unable to change background image in custom EditText class

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view

I have a Custom EditTextClass that Im using for all EditTexts on my App -

```
Class CustomEditText : EditText {
...
}
```

I want to change the background image, so that it should be reflected in all the usages of this CustomEditText.

I tried this -

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas ? ) {
    val d = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(mContext!!, R.drawable.new_drawable)
    d?.draw(canvas!!)
    super.onDraw(canvas)
}
```

and this -

```
fun init(context: Context ? , attrs : AttributeSet ? ) {
    background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context!!.getResources(), R.drawable.new_drawable, null)
    setBackground(background)
}
```

Both the ways, don't work. Can anyone tell me what is the correct solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `setBounds` to `drawable` when draw drawable.
So you should make your draw method like this.

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas? ) {
    val d = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context!!, R.drawable.new_drawable)
    d?.setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
    d?.draw(canvas!!)
    super.onDraw(canvas)
}
```

Comment: I've tested upper code in my env. It works perfectly. And then Could you share more code? so i can debug. And did you checked your drawable resource?

Comment: my apologies. its my mistake. your code works.

Comment: glad to help you.

Comment: @Daniel.Wang super.onDraw(canvas) must be on the bottom, is not it?

Answer (score 1):

First draw to `canvas` and pass the `canvas` to `parent` meaning `super.onDraw` should be at bottom

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas ? ) {
    val d = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(mContext!!, R.drawable.new_drawable)
    d?.draw(canvas!!)
    super.onDraw(canvas)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should **not** override `onDraw` method as this could cause issues when `super.onDraw(canvas)` is called before your operations (your drawable could cover the text, hits, drawable elements, etc.).

I've made a demo, which worked for me:

```
class CustomEditText : AppCompatEditText {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init()
    }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        init()
    }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context,
                                                                                   attrs,
                                                                                   defStyleAttr) {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_drawable)
    }
}
```